# Overclock cause fro system crash in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, update-manager, crash

I have an overclocked system that has been running a 9700k@4.9Ghz for about a year now. I have never had a crash due to overclocked cpu.
However, I wanted to set up a ubuntu installation just for fun to play with RetroPie. I set up a dual boot system on my nvme drive, allocating 26 gb to ubuntu.
Installation and everything went fine, until I started to clone RetroPie-Setup from git.
My system got rebooted three times during the process, no error message or anything ( I don't know how to check error logs in ubuntu, yet)
So I reset everything in my BIOS (I have an Asus z390 Prime) and booted again into ubuntu. The installation process went through rather smoothely. I monitored the clock speeds, they were in tehir normal range for non-oc CPU.

Again, in Windows, I never had any crashed due to overclocking. I finetuned that cpu when I first got it.

So my question is this: Is this a possibility that ocing could be the cause for my system crashes? Could anyone point me to some insightful logs, perhaps in /var/logs ? That I could provide?

I don't like the fact that I have to change my BIOS Profile for ubuntu, should that in fact be the cause.

Comment: I doubt your processor cares what operating system its working for! Sounds like the thing that changed when you installed Ubuntu and RetroPie was the usage of the nvme drive. ie more or different parts of the available memory, or it was just an unexplained crash.

Comment: I was able to replicate that crash by running the "Basic Install" command in RetroPie-Setup. When I ran the same command with Default-BIOS settings, the machine doesn't crash. In Windows, the machine sustains even heavy stress testing using Cinebench with the OC-Settings. I would like to study a log file of some sorts, ubuntu must have logged something about these crashes?

Comment: A good place to start is (in a terminal) “journalctl -b0 -p3”. This will show system errors in the last boot. Use -b1 for the boot before that and so on. Omit -b# for all boots in log. -p3 asks for errors and above. RetroPie may have its own error log.